# Printing Unicode characters to the shell

Tags: windows, unicode, cmd, raku

I'd like to output a Unicode character in `cmd`, but the obvious approach fails:

```
C:\Windows\System32>perl6 -e "'Я'.say"
?
```

Interestingly, this works:

```
C:\Windows\System32>perl6 -e "Buf.new(0xD0, 0xAF).decode('UTF-8').say"
Я
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Edit: I'm using the most recent Rakudo Star release from [here](http://rakudo.org/downloads/star/).

```
C:\Windows\System32>perl6 -v
This is Rakudo version 2016.01.1 built on MoarVM version 2016.01
implementing Perl 6.c.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a lack of testing on Windows. Please file a bug report against Rakudo. If you got a recent Rakudo Star version that is.

**Update:** Bug was filed and the issue has since been fixed.

```
C:\Windows\System32>perl6 -v
This is Rakudo version 2017.04.3 built on MoarVM version 2017.04-53-g66c6dda
implementing Perl 6.c.

C:\Windows\System32>perl6 -e "'Я'.say"
Я
```

[Sinan Ünür](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100754/sinan-%c3%9cn%c3%bcr) has written an interesting [blog post](https://www.nu42.com/2017/02/unicode-windows-command-line.html) on the problem.